# Does the hypergeometric function of a matrix argument depend on $\alpha$ for a $1\times 1$ matrix?

Tags: special-functions, symmetric-functions, hypergeometric-functions

I already posted this question on maths.SE but got no answer.

The hypergeometric function of a matrix argument has form
$$
{}_pF_q^{(\alpha)}(a_1, \ldots, a_p; b_1, \ldots, b_q;X) = 
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{\kappa\vdash k} c^{(\alpha)}_{a,b} J^{(\alpha)}_\kappa(X), 
$$
where $J^{(\alpha)}_\kappa(X)$ is a (normalized) Jack polynomial: $J^{(\alpha)}_\kappa(X) = J^{(\alpha)}_\kappa(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ where the $x_i$ are the eigenvalues of $X$.

I have implemented [Koev & Edelman's algorithm](http://math.mit.edu/~edelman/homepage/papers/hypers.pdf) for the evaluation of ${}_pF_q^{(\alpha)}$. According to my implementation, ${}_pF_q^{(\alpha)}$ does not depend on $\alpha$ when $n = 1$ (and in this  case we find the classical generalized hypergeometric function).

However, there is another implementation in the [CharFunToolR package for R](https://github.com/gajdosandrej/CharFunToolR?files=1) (also based on Koev-Edelman algorithm, but not strictly following the algorithm given in the paper), and with this implementation, ${}_pF_q^{(\alpha)}$ does depend on $\alpha$ when $n = 1$ (for $\alpha=1$ the results coincide with my results).

So I'm wondering: *does ${}_pF_q^{(\alpha)}$ depend on $\alpha$ when $n = 1$ ?*

Comment: According to a remark in [these notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.4568), the answer is no.